# Passing data between forms in c#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to pass data of the cost of flights to a different form, however when ever I type in the code there is an error "checkIn.toshortdatestring". I'm not sure if there is a simpler way of doing this or if I've placed my code in the wrong area.

```
private void btn_cost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string location = cbo_location.SelectedItem.ToString();            
    DateTime checkIn = dtp_out.Value;
    frm_details Frm_flights = new frm_details(txt_flightcost, checkIn.toshortdatestring);

    Frm_flights.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: `ToShortDateString()` is a function call but you have no `()` in your call. And C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: google -> C# DateTime toshortdatestring -> Lucky shot -> [result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Should be `.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: ive now got that fixed however now the "frm_details" is now an error  'frm_details' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments BookingForm

Comment: look for frm_details constructor. If you are sending two parameters you should have the parameters set on constructor definition

Comment: @MikeDebela that´s his object name. The type is frm_details. It is a naming convention violation. And SO code parser does not recognize

Answer (score 1):

Your initial mistake seems to be that you are not calling well ToShortDateString():

```
frm_details Frm_flights = new frm_details(txt_flightcost, checkIn.ToShortDateString());
```

Anyway, your code also seems to be violating several naming conventions. I copy here a link where you can take a look at naming conventions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040(v=vs.110).aspx